# Getting image path from the iPhone camera Using UIImagePickerController return nil

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to get the image path from camera using `UIImagePickerController`

here is the code :

```
 @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker?.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker?.delegate = self
        imagePicker?.sourceType = .Camera

        presentViewController(imagePicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
        print(" Path \(imageURL)")
        imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView?.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as?        UIImage
        imagePicker?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` gets called after a pic is taken using the camera. `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` object will be `nil` as the image has not been saved to the camera roll yet.

To get rid of this situation, you need to first save the image and then use the url of the path you saved. You can however use `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` property on `info` to show the taken image in your application. Hope this helps!

Comment: Quick update, as of Swift 5 iOS 12 `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL ` is deprecated and instead use... either `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL` OR `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL`

Answer (score 14):

I use this method to save the image taken via camera

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print(info)
    var selectedImage: UIImage!
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = image
    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = image
    }
    self.profileImageView.image = selectedImage

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {

        let imgName = UUID().uuidString
        let documentDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let localPath = documentDirectory.appending(imgName)

        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.3)! as NSData
        data.write(toFile: localPath, atomically: true)
        let photoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath)


    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround for getting the image local pat!